# iPhone Custom Page control buttons

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

Is it possible to control a page controller with custom buttons instead of the Page control dots? Similar to a jQuery slider in js?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "page controller"? There is no such thing in the iPhone SDK. `UIPageControl` is a very dumb control that has no connection to the scroll view whose page it usually displays. The developer has to manually keep them in sync. So it is no problem at all to use your own custom page control view and manually sync it with a scroll view.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ole. I downloaded the ScrollView project from Apple and hashed out a UIToolbar solution to control the scrollview using scrollRectToVisible.